# Getting random date and time between two dates using php carbon

Tags: php, php-carbon

I'm using laravel and carbon and want to generate random date and time between today and 30 days ago, something like `2023-08-28 13:50:14`

if I use it like this

```
$randomDateTime = Carbon::now()->subDays(rand(0, 30));
```

I got the date randomized, but it will always got current time, is there a possibility to random the time also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `subSeconds()` to achieve this.

```
$randomDateTime = Carbon::now()->subSeconds(rand(0, 30 * 24 * 60 * 60));
```

Comment: thank you, I think this is the simpler one

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code a bit while maintaining your 30 days requirement.

Add `startOfDay()` to get "00:00:00" and `addSeconds()` for random number between 23 hours, 59 minutes, and 59 seconds.

```
$randomDateTime = Carbon::now()->subDays(rand(0, 30))->startOfDay()-addSeconds(rand(0, 86399));
```